# Timeout when unioning two select all queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to union two SQL queries together which look roughly like this:

```
SELECT *, "table1" as table_name
FROM table_one
INNER JOIN
another_table_one
ON
another_table_one.id = table_one.id
UNION
SELECT *, "table2" as table_name
FROM table_two
INNER JOIN
another_table_two
ON
another_table_two.id = table_two.id
```

Running the two queries individually runs fine and returns the same columns in the same order, but when I union them together it will time out after 60s. If any of you can help I would be really grateful!

The database I'm working with is MySQL, the individual queries return 10 columns and I don't think it's to do with the amount of rows being returned because I have tried to limit the rows to 10 and it still times out.

Comment: Please share more details. Is this a MySQL problem, or a PostgreSQL problem? How many rows are in there? What does the execution plan tell you about the query?

Comment: try a EXPLAIN or ANALYSE on the query and increase the time ount

Comment: Change UNION to `UNION ALL`.

Comment: @gannothor, check if you have ```index``` defined on ```id``` for ```table_one``` & ```another_table_one```

Comment: Not a good idea to use *. Try to identiify the fields you require and retrieve only the fields you need for performance improvement. Also check your indexes are done on the proper fields and try profiling the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL`.  `UNION` incurs the overhead of removing duplicates.  And this is unnecessary *between* the two results sets (because the last column is different), and presumably unnecessary *within* each result set.

So:

```
SELECT *, 'table1' as table_name
FROM table_one INNER JOIN
     another_table_one
     ON another_table_one.id = table_one.id
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'table2' as table_name
FROM table_two INNER JOIN
     another_table_two
     ON another_table_two.id = table_two.id
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT a. * , 'table1' AS tblname FROM (SELECT *
FROM table_one
INNER JOIN
another_table_one
ON
another_table_one.id = table_one.id) AS  'a'
UNION

SELECT b.* , 'table2' AS tblname FROM (

SELECT *
FROM table_two
INNER JOIN
another_table_two
ON
another_table_two.id = table_two.id ) AS 'b'

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What have you changed, ahdn why?